# Amazon Lightsail VPS not working with Nginx? (Django React project deployment)

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, server, vps

I've newly registered with Amazon VPS service, Amazon Lightsail. After properly setup my Django app, Gunicorn and Nginx, it seems that there's some problem with the traffic?

I set up the same Django app on two different VPS using the same process, both with Ubuntu 18.

The IP isn't working on AWS (13.124.94.92):

```sh
~# ping -c3 13.124.94.92
PING 13.124.94.92 (13.124.94.92) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 13.124.94.92 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2044ms
```

The IP is working perfectly (5.63.152.4) in another VPS Ubuntu 18:

```sh
~# ping -c3 5.63.152.4
PING 5.63.152.4 (5.63.152.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 5.63.152.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 5.63.152.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 5.63.152.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms

--- 5.63.152.4 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2043ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.063/0.084/0.108/0.019 ms
```

The first IP isn't showing 'Welcome to Nginx' page while the second does (http://5.63.152.4/)

I'm not sure where to start to debug this... I've fiddled with `iptables` a bit, for failing to have `mosh` working. Please help! Thanks!!!

### Additional Info:

Firewall active

```sh
~$  sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
60000:61000/udp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
mosh                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
60000:61000/udp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
mosh (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

nginx status

```sh
~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

/etc/nginx/{sites-available, sites-enabled}/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

gunicorn status

```sh
~$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-05-01 06:14:48 UTC; 1h 17min ago
 Main PID: 14512 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 517)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other newbie like me:

Problem solved... Amazon Lightsail has its own firewall under 'Networking' tag on the control panel. So no need to set `ufw` yourself in Ubuntu. The welcome page of Nginx simply does not show. Once you are done pointing your domain to the public IP of the Lightsail instance, you are all set.

My particular problem was, Django require SSL access because of the settings I made. Hence, after SSL is installed using cerbot the website is accessible.

PS. It's a good idea to disable the 8000 port before finishing off your deployment.